# VHDL concurrent selective assignment synthesis

Tags: vhdl

a real junior question with hopefully a junior answer, regarding one of the main assignments of VHDL (concurrent selective assignment) can anyone explain what a VHDL compiler would synthesise the following description into?

```
LIBRARY IEEE;
USE IEEE.std_logic_1164.ALL;
USE IEEE.numeric_std.ALL;

ENTITY Q2 IS
PORT (a,b,c,d           :   IN  std_logic;
        EW_NS           :   OUT std_logic
        );
END ENTITY Q2;

ARCHITECTURE hybrid OF Q2 IS
SIGNAL INPUT                        :   std_logic_vector(3 DOWNTO 0);
SIGNAL EW_NS                        :   std_logic;

BEGIN
INPUT <= (a & b & c & d); -- concatination

WITH (INPUT) SELECT
        EW_NS <= '1' WHEN "0001"|"0010"|"0011"|"0110"|"1011",
                 '0' WHEN OTHERS;
END ARCHITECTURE hybrid;
```

Why do I ask? well I have previously gone about things the wrong way i.e. describing things on VHDL before making a block diagram of the components needed. I would envisage this been synthed as a group of and gate logic ?
Any help would be really helpful.
Thanks D

Comment: May I suggest that you download the free [Altera Quartus Prime Lite Edition](http://dl.altera.com/?edition=lite), and synthesize the design, and then you can easily see for yourself.  It will be a very hand tool in your future adventures, and it even comes with a free ModelSim version[.](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/give_a_man_a_fish_and_you_feed_him_for_a_day;_teach_a_man_to_fish_and_you_feed_him_for_a_lifetime)

Comment: Hi Mr Zimmer, I have the Quartus II sp13.01 along with ModelSim Altera starter edition 10.1d. This is what I use for description and "test bench" at the moment, I have not got to test bench, use yet :/ although I hear some of you guys talk about it. I was asking to know what the "description" would synth to, logic gate wise.  Again Thank you for previous and future help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to look at the user guide for your target FPGA, and understand what is contained within one 'logic element' ('slice' in Xilinx terminology). In general an FPGA does not implement combinatorial logic by connecting up discrete gates like AND, OR, etc. Instead, a logic element will contain one or more 'look-up tables', with typically four (but now 6 in some newer devices) inputs. The inputs to this look up table (LUT) are the inputs to your logic function, and the output is *one* of the outputs of the function. The LUT is then programmed as a ROM, allowing your input signals to function as an address. There is one ROM entry for every possible combination of inputs, with the result being the intended logic function.

A function with several outputs would simply use several of these LUTs in parallel, with the same inputs, one LUT for each of the function's outputs. A function requiring more inputs than the LUT has (say, 7 inputs, where a LUT has only 4), simply combines two LUTs in parallel, using a multiplexer to choose between the output of the two LUTs. This final multiplexer uses one of the input signals as it's control, and again every possible combination of inputs is accounted for.

This may sound inefficient for creating something simple like an AND gate, but the benefit is that this simple building block (a LUT) can implement absolutely any combinatorial function. It's also worth noting that an FPGA tool chain is extremely good at optimising logic functions in order to simplify them, and to better map them into the FPGA. The LUT provides a highly generic element for these tools to target.

A logic element will also contain some dedicated resources for functions that aren't well suited to the LUT approach. These might include dedicated carry chains for adders, multiplexers for combining the output of several LUTS, registers (most designs are synchronous). LUTs can also sometimes be configured as small shift registers or RAM elements. External to the logic elements, there will be more specific blocks like large multipliers, larger memories, PLLs, etc, none of which can be as efficiently implemented using LUT resource. Again, this will all be explained in the user guide for your target FPGA.

Comment: Thank you scary_jeff. A really good explanation :) When dealing with terminology correlating around CPU's I find general text books lack conformity around the matter (depending on date of publish) and tend to skip some of this text. Thanks :) I will take time and re read...

Comment: @DanielJHall If you're happy with it, would you mind marking this one as accepted as well? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Back in the day, your code would have been implemented as a single 74150 TTL circuit, which is a 16-to-1 mux. you have a 4-bit select (`INPUT`), and this selects one of 16 inputs to the chip, which is routed to a single output ('EW_NS`). The 74150 is obsolete and I can't find any datasheets, but it's easy to find diagrams of what an 8-to-1 mux looks like ([here](https://mazharlaliwala.wordpress.com/2011/03/15/data-processing-circuits/), for example). The 16->1 is identical, but everything is wider. My old TI databook shows basically exactly the diagram at this link doubled up.

But - wait. Your problem is easier, because you're not routing real inputs to the output - you're just setting fixed data values. On the '150, you do this by wiring 5 of the 16 inputs to 1, and the remaining 11 to 0. This makes the logic much easier.

The 74150 has basiscally exactly the same functionality as a 4-input look-up table (where the fixed look-up data is the same as fixed levels at the '150 inputs), so it's trivial to implement your entire circuit in a single LUT in an FPGA, as per scary_jeff's answer, rather than using a NAND-level implementation. In a proper chip, though, it would be implemented as a sum-of-products, or something similar (exactly what's in the linked diagram). In this case, draw a K-map and find a minimum solution. My 2 minutes on the back of an envelope comes up with three 3-input AND gates, driving a 3-input OR gate. I'll leave it as an exercise to you to check this :)

Comment: Thank you EML, yes I get     Db.Cb.A + Cb.B.A + Db.B.Ab